# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to the ASP .net core. I typed a web api and I'm trying to search in another project but I'm getting an error.

[image]

> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task
> sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts,
> bool disposeCts) BookWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in
> HomeController.cs
> +
> HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/books/");
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[]
> arguments) System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask actionResultValueTask)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref
> State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

BookAPI/Controllers/BooksControler.cs

```cs
    namespace BookAPI.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class BooksController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly BookDbContext _context;
     
            public BooksController(BookDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
     
            // GET: api/Books
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetProducts()
            {
                return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
            }
    
    
            
            // GET: api/Books/5
            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> GetBook(int id)
            {
                var book = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
     
                if (book == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
     
                return book;
            }
     
            // PUT: api/Book/5
            [HttpPut("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> PutBook(int id, Book book)
            {
                if (id != book.Id)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
     
                _context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
     
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!BookExists(id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
     
                return NoContent();
            }
     
            // POST: api/Books
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> PostBook(Book book)
            {
                _context.Books.Add(book);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     
                return CreatedAtAction("GetBook", new { id = book.Id }, book);
            }
     
            // DELETE: api/Books/5
            [HttpDelete("{id}")]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> DeleteBook(int id)
            {
                var book = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
                if (book == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
     
                _context.Books.Remove(book);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     
                return book;
            }
     
            private bool BookExists(int id)
            {
                return _context.Books.Any(e => e.Id == id);
            }
        }
    }
```

BookAPI/Properties/launchSettings.json

```json
    {
      "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
      "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:32803/",
          "sslPort": 44393
        }
      },
      "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        },
        "BookAPI": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

BookWeb/Helper/Helper.cs

```cs
namespace BookWeb.Helper
{
    public class  BookAPI
    {
        public HttpClient Initial()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:32803/");
            return client;
        }
    }
    
}
```

BookWeb/Controllers/HomeControler.cs

```cs
    namespace BookWeb.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            BookAPI _api = new BookAPI();
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                List<Book> book = new List<Book>();
                HttpClient client = _api.Initial();
                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/books/");
                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var results = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(results);
                }
                return View(book);
            }
    
    
            public IActionResult Privacy()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
            [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
            public IActionResult Error()
            {
                return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it says right in the error that it can't connect to the server.

Comment: I don't like code - await client.GetAsync("api/books/"); try to change it to await client.GetAsync("api/books");

Comment: I suggest that you could try the url:`https://localhost:44393/` or `http://localhost:44393/`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:32803/");
```

use

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:32803");
```

and instead of

```
await client.GetAsync("api/books/")
```

use

```
await client.GetAsync("api/books")
```